# sprintf in opa rego policy

Tags: opa, rego

I have sprintf in one of the rule, but does not seem to be working. This is very basic but can someone tell me what am I doing wrong? Both online on https://play.openpolicyagent.org/ as well offline with opa version 0.32.0 does not seem to be working.

```
package cs

deny[reason] {
    input.spec.resourceAttributes.namespace == "sveltos"
    reason := sprintf("OPA: User (%v) must belong to valid group", input.spec.user)
}
```

Input:

```
{
  "spec": {
    "resourceAttributes": {
      "namespace": "sveltos",
      "resource": "pods"
    },
    "user": "jane"
  }
}
```

Answer (score 4):

It was my mistake, opa does not yet have varargs functions, so the second argument to sprintf must be an array. In the example:

```
package cs

deny[reason] {
    input.spec.resourceAttributes.namespace == "sveltos"
    reason := sprintf("OPA: User (%v) must belong to valid group", [input.spec.user])
}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
package kubeeye_nodes_rego

deny[msg] {
    resource := input
    type := resource.Object.kind
    resourcename := resource.Object.metadata.name
    type == "Node"
    level := "waring"

    cpuAllocatable := to_number(resource.Object.status.allocatable.cpu)
    cpuCapacity := to_number(resource.Object.status.capacity.cpu)
    percent := 1 - cpuAllocatable/cpuCapacity
    msg := {
        "Name": sprintf("%v", [resourcename]),
        "Type": sprintf("%v", [type]),
        "Level": sprintf("%v", [level]),
        "Message": sprintf("[CPU] Allocatable: %d, Capacity: %d, Ava: %f", [cpuAllocatable,cpuCapacity,percent]),
    }
}
```

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).